# Not able to capture the image with BufferedImage buffimg =ImageIO.read(new URL(webImageLoc)) in Selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java, image-comparison, ashot

I am trying to compare the page logo by downloading it first and after taking its screenshot. Below is the LUMA logo that I am trying to verify via Selenium WebDriver Java with Cucumber:

[image]

I am using AShot API to compare the logo.

I tried below code in Selenium:
My PageObject function:

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage {

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
    
    // Declaring global parameters
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    
    //Elements for page details 
    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@aria-label='store logo']//img")
    WebElement logoLuma;

        public boolean compareHomePageLogo() throws IOException {
        boolean results = false;
        WebElement imgLuma = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(logoLuma));
        
        // First downloading the logo image and storing it in local machine
        String webImageLoc = imgLuma.getAttribute("src");
        //System.out.println("URL is: " + new URL(webImageLoc));
        BufferedImage buffimg =ImageIO.read(new URL(webImageLoc));
        System.out.println(buffimg);
        File outputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Screenshots\\expected.png");
        ImageIO.write(buffimg, "png", outputFile);
        
        // Taking screenshot of image element from search results
            Screenshot shot = new AShot().takeScreenshot(driver, imgLuma);
            File screenshotFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Screenshots\\actual.png");
        ImageIO.write(shot.getImage(), "png", screenshotFile);
        
        // Comparing both images
        BufferedImage expectedImage = ImageIO.read(outputFile); // Getting expected image
        BufferedImage actualImage = shot.getImage(); // Getting actual image
        
        ImageDiffer imgDiff = new ImageDiffer();
        ImageDiff diff = imgDiff.makeDiff(expectedImage, actualImage); // Storing diff result
        if(diff.hasDiff()) {
            System.out.println("Images are not same.");
            results = false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Images are same.");
            results = true;
        }
        
        return results;
    }
}
```

My Step definition which is calling above function:

```
@Then("user can see the LUMA image on page")
public void user_can_see_the_luma_image_on_page() {
    hp = new HomePage(driver);
    try {
        Assert.assertTrue("Images are not same.", hp.compareHomePageLogo());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

Here is the TestRunner:

```
package testRunner;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions
        (
            features = { ".//src/test/resources/Features/LandingPage.feature" },
            glue = "stepDefinitions",
            plugin = 
            {
                "pretty",
                "html:reports/myreport.html",
                "json:reports/myreport.json",
                "rerun:target/rerun.txt", // Mandatory to capture failures
                "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json",
                "junit:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.xml",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"
            },
                    
            dryRun = false,
            monochrome = true,
               tags = "@temp"
            )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Running the above TestRunner with JUnit, getting below error in console:

```
  Given user navigates to "https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/" # stepDefinitions.HomePageSteps.user_navigates_to(java.lang.String)
  When user can see the "Default welcome msg!" on page                # stepDefinitions.HomePageSteps.user_can_see_the_on_page(java.lang.String)
**null**
15:01:19.989 [main] INFO  stepDefinitions.HomePageSteps - **image == null!**
  Then user can see the LUMA image on page                            # stepDefinitions.HomePageSteps.user_can_see_the_luma_image_on_page()
      java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:87)
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:96)
    at stepDefinitions.HomePageSteps.user_can_see_the_luma_image_on_page(HomePageSteps.java:109)
    at ✽.user can see the LUMA image on page(file:///C:/Users/priyank.shah3/eclipse-workspace/Luma_eCommerce/./src/test/resources/Features/LandingPage.feature:17)

Scenario status ======>FAILED
```

As shown above, I am getting "image == null" (highlighted in bold). I tried troubleshooting by printing logs and came to know that it's not reading the file on below line on my PageObject class:

```
BufferedImage buffimg =ImageIO.read(new URL(webImageLoc));
```

Tried searching the possible solutions but nothing works till date. Need help on how to get the image here.

Comment: What comes in `webImageLoc`?

Comment: @AlexeyR. It's the Logo URL: https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/pub/static/version1666447838/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/logo.svg

I attached the same in the image in very first paragraph under DOM. You can take reference from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your logo is in `svg` format. While `ImageIO` does not support a lot of formats (`svg` is one of the formats which are not supported out of the box) there are the opprotunities to add support for particular image format.

Check the solution from this post: https://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/usage-imageio.html